# Using MEF to import a WPF DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, mef

I was looking at MEF as an extensibility framework, and I'm pretty much sold, except for one point:

Let's say I want to import both a ViewModel and a View to display it.  I think the "right" way to do that is for the MEF part to export a ViewModel class, and a DataTemplate that displays the ViewModel.  As an example, say you were building a Visio-like application and you want to import a library of shapes.  Each shape needs a View defined in Xaml and a ViewModel that would wrap some underlying Model object.

Is this possible?  What would the Import contract look like for the DataTemplate and how do I make WPF aware of the imported DataTemplate?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, I was able to make this work in the following way:

In my host WPF application, I added this Import:

```
    [ImportMany("ApplicationResources", typeof(ResourceDictionary))]
    public IEnumerable<ResourceDictionary> Views { get; set; }
```

Then in my composite part, I declared a ViewModel, and a data template for the ViewModel in a regular ResourceDictionary Xaml file.  Then I created a code behind for the ResourceDictionary, like this (in this example, the ViewModel is called ItemViewModel and the ResourceDictionary is called ItemView):

```
[Export("ApplicationResources", typeof(ResourceDictionary))]
public partial class ItemView : ResourceDictionary 
{
    public ItemView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

For reference, the Xaml for the example ResourceDictionary looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyCompany.MyProduct"
    x:Class="MyCompany.MyProduct.ItemView">

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemViewModel}">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then, back in my host WPF application, after I successfully compose and before I show the main window, I do this:

```
// Add the imported resource dictionaries
// to the application resources
foreach (ResourceDictionary r in Views)
{
    this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(r);
}
```

That seems to successfully apply the DataTemplate anywhere WPF sees an ItemViewModel.

**EDIT**: For anyone who's interested, I released an application framework called [SoapBox Core](http://soapboxcore.com/) as open source, and it uses this method extensively to import Views into the application resources.  It works very well, and you can download the source yourself and take a look at how it works.

Comment: I tried this exact approach but the ResourceDictionary is empty at load time.  Is there a way to force initialization or am I doing something wrong?