# How to get at ResourceDictionary style when it is loaded from external xap and assemblies are MEF-fed?

Tags: silverlight, assemblies, mef, resourcedictionary, xap

I've got the following setup:

The main application loads a XAP with an IPlugin implementation. The Plugin contains a 'DisplayPanel' that contains a referenced Control with other controls. The DisplayPanel here is simply a container control to show referenced Control.

This referenced Control, from an assembly, uses a Style from a ResourceDictionary xaml in this assembly. At least that's what I want to have. The problem is that the referenced Control throws an error:

> Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key PlayerPanelGrad [Line: 1500
>   Position: 127]

I've tried to get at the style by referencing theResourceDictionary through a Merged Resource dictionary reference:

```
       <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="TableControls;component/ControlsStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

But that doesn't work.

How would you approch this?

Answer (score 1):

the only way i got it to work is by loading the Resource dictionary into the control (in a Class Library) programmatically before the InitializeComponent call:

```
public ActionPanel()
{
     StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(
          new Uri("TableControls;component/ControlsStyle.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
     Application.Current.Resources.Add("plop",sr.Stream);
     // Required to initialize variables
     InitializeComponent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question may be of help, although, honestly, I'm still trying to figure it out myself:
[Using MEF to import a WPF DataTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842571/using-mef-to-import-a-wpf-datatemplate)

Answer (score 0):

//load other.dll dynamically first,and then use the following code:

```
       StreamResourceInfo srf = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("otherdll;component/Resources/Brush.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(srf.Stream);
        string stt = sr.ReadToEnd();
        ResourceDictionary dict = XamlReader.Load(stt) as ResourceDictionary;
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, my XAML file was found in a subdirectory of the solution which needed the `/` character but also file was further in a subdirectory named `Assets` within it.

```
<ResourceDictionary 
     Source="/MyAssemblyName;component/Assets/RadResources.xaml" />
```

Also the .XAML file was built as `Page` in the solution.