# How to apply styles in a resource dictionary that is programmatically added to the App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries collection?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mef, silverlight-5.0

I am working with a very large Silverlight 5 application that needs to implement theming. Unfortunately I can't use the C1 (Component One) or Silverlight Toolkit theme mechanisms due to the enormity of xaml and code changes I would have to implement. I am forced to do something a bit out of the box.

As a starting point I created a demo project by referencing a post on Stack Overflow [Using Mef to Import a WPF DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842571/using-mef-to-import-a-wpf-datatemplate) written by @Scott Whitlock. The post described how to dynamically load a Silverlight/WPF resource dictionary and add it to the `App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries` collection within the Silverlight/WPF application.

I created 4 projects. The first being the Silverlight 5 application itself, the second, third, and forth are silverlight class libraries for defining all the theme particulars. Each class library has an entry point which is a derived type of `ResourceDictionary`.

On AppStart event, the application loads the default theme class library, which is essentially a blank slate with all default styles defined in Silverlight. By loading I mean the the `DefaultTheme` resource dictionary defined within the class library is added to the `App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries` collection.

When the user selects another theme from a combo box within the app, the code removes the existing default theme and adds the blue or red, or whatever other theme's entry point resource dictionary to the `App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries` collection.

However, even though no errors have been thrown when this action occurs, the styles themselves are never re-applied. I have verified that each theme has the same style keys across the board.

Any ideas on how to force the `App.Current.RootVisual` re-apply the styles from the newly added resource dictionary after a "theme switch" ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for the current ResourceDictionary first and removing it before adding the new ResourceDictionary.

```
string themeName = "White";
string oldThemeName = "Black";
string oldResourcePathString = String.Format("/Library.Name;component/Themes/{0}Theme.xaml", oldThemeName);
StreamResourceInfo sriOldTheme = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(oldResourcePathString, UriKind.Relative));

if (sriOldTheme != null)
{
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sriOldTheme.Stream);
  object resourceObject = XamlReader.Load(sr.ReadToEnd());

  ResourceDictionary resource = resourceObject as ResourceDictionary;
  if (resource != null)
  {
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(resource);
  }
}

string resourcePathString = String.Format("/Library.Name;component/Themes/{0}Theme.xaml", themeName);
StreamResourceInfo sriTheme = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(resourcePathString, UriKind.Relative));

if (sriTheme != null)
{
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sriTheme.Stream);
  object resourceObject = XamlReader.Load(sr.ReadToEnd());

  ResourceDictionary resource = resourceObject as ResourceDictionary;
  if (resource != null)
  {
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resource);
  }
}
```

I never tested the code, so check for typos, but this should work whether you set the ResourceDictionary in App.xaml or programatically from MainPage.xaml.cs