# How to load DataTemplate from another Assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, resourcedictionary

Here's the situation:
 Assembly `Common` implements `CommonMessageBox.xaml` window with `ContentControl` bound to its `DataContext`. Assembly `AnotherAssembly` implements `MyViewModel` class and a `ResourceDictionary` with some `DataTemplate` for the `MyViewModel`. It also references the `Common` assembly. I want to show`CommonMessageBox` window and assign object of `MyViewModel` type to its `DataContext`.

The question is: (How) can I (elegantly and preferrably in XAML) *inject* `ResourceDictionary` from `AnotherAssembly` to `CommonMessageBox` window's resources *without* changing the `Common` assembly or `App.xaml`?

This solution works, but I was wondering if there is another/simpler/more elegant way?

```
CommonMessageBox w = new CommonMessageBox();
w.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
w.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(@"/AnotherAssembly;component/DataTemplateDictionary.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
w.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

In App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         <ResourceDictionary Source = "/AnotherAssembly;component/DataTemplateDictionary.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In CommonMessageBox.xaml you can also set your DataContext like this

```
<UserControl xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:AnotherAssemblyNamespace;assembly=AnotherAssembly">
   <UserControl.DataContext>
      <viewmodels:MyViewModel />
   </UserControl.DataContext>
</UserControl>
```

Now you can change those App.xaml references using code I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390286/how-to-apply-styles-in-a-resource-dictionary-that-is-programmatically-added-to-t/25044255#25044255).

Comment: I don't want to change App.xaml because I don't want to recompile my .EXE file. I just want to modify `AnotherAssembly` project.

Comment: ok, well the link I gave shows you how to do:     Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resource);